# Guessing rectangle hypotenuse angle from proportion between it's sides

Tags: angle, rectangles

if a rectangle has it's width as double it's height, can I assume that his hypotenuse will divide the his angle in a proportion of 2:1, or as the angle is 90, the angles would be divided so one part is 30 and the other 60?

Comment: The answer is no. The angle of the diagonal of a rectangle can be found by taking the inverse tangent of the ratio of the sides. So the the larger angle is $\approx 63.43 ^{\circ}$

Comment: @Tbw Thank you so much!